# Tomcat can not shut down gracefully

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat with application runs in Linux.
In ServletContextListener contextDestroyed I stop all possible APIs I use.
It sometimes dies by "catalina stop -force", sometimes not. When not, then I use "kill -9". Most probably it's kept by some resource/loop. 
Which system tools can be used for diagnosing?
Where else to debug beside contextDestroyed?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a thread is running that is not properly terminated. In order to find out which one that is, stop tomcat (incompletely) and then create a thread dump by issuing `kill -3 <pid>`. The thread dump will be printed to sysout (or was it syserr?) and you can check what's still running. Hopefully they have somewhat descriptive names or stacktraces that you can recognize what you're dealing with.

Then fix the component that you've identified to properly shutdown that thread, or make it a daemon upon creation, so that tomcat can shut down with it running.

Comment: Good idea, thank you. Something strange: When tracing "catalina.sh stop -force" with bash -X, I saw it printing 5 times "kill -0 PID", then "kill -9 PID". In remote debug it one time entered tomcat app's contextDestroy. However, when running kill -0 PID as a stand-alone command it never entered contextDestroy???!!! It fact, as stand alone it entered contextDestroy only as a reaction to kill -n PID, where n is not "0", say "1" for example.